# Google App Script - how to remove granted OAuth permissions?

Tags: oauth, google-apps-script, permissions

I explored some functions in Google App Script and added the requested OAuth permissions to my script.

[AppScript Permissions Image in Google Sheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A3I1b.png)

But finally I removed the particular function calls. How can I remove the granted permissions??

Regars klaus

Answer (score 2):

The  OAuth Scopes in that list are displayed automatically based on a scan of the code, just keep in mind that even if your code is commented yet an authorization request will be generated and will be displayed in that list

Comment: I already deleted the code and still have to grant the permissions for that. How long will it take? The code scan should be immediately..

Answer (score 2):

Very easy, if you set the OAuth manually, the others OAuth are deleted automatically.

To set the OAuth manually, you need to open the "appscript.json" file located in [Script Menu Bar] > [View] > [Show manifest file], and include the OAuth that you need as below:

```
"oauthScopes": ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email", "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets"],
```